# Decisions using methods

Tags: java

> #### Task:
>
> - Includes Decisions, and all constructs above.
> - Defines and uses methods including one(s) that take an argument and return a result
>
> Example: As above, but the program now has a series of possible template lines to go in the love letter in addition to the above and chooses which one to include at random. For example it might choose between a line of the form “You are my <noun>” and a line “I will forever think of you as my <noun>”. The person running the program inputs a noun when asked (eg “snugglebunny”) to complete the sentence (e.g., in this case it might then choose “You are my snugglebunny”). For each template, a separate method is defined that returns the full sentence given the word supplied as an argument.

This is the code I managed to get done, however it's showing errors "String [] cannot be converted to String for printmessage(ans1, input)". I don't know where I am going wrong with this question, would be glad if someone could help!

```
public static void decisions()
    {
        String input; 
        String phrase = "";

        input = askquestion ();  // defining the method for asking user the question to input a noun word.

        String [] ans1 = {"You remind me of my","I always think of you as my","I wish You could always be my","you are my one and only"};   // this will randomly select one phrase out of 4 given

        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 4);  //this will do a random math calculation and select one phrase

        switch (rand)
                {
                case 0:
                printmessage(ans1, input);
                break;

                case 1:
                printmessage(ans1, input);
                break;

                case 2:
                printmessage(ans1, input);
                break;

                case 3:
                printmessage(ans1, input);
                break;
                }   

         // this defines the method for printing the message, taking the argument strings inside the bracket to the message defined later on.

    } // END decisions


    public static String askquestion ()

    {
        String result = "";

        result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a noun word to describe your partner"); //asks users input

        return result;
    }

    public static void printmessage (String ans1, String input) // this will receive the argument from the method defined above and then be printed below as shown. The argument have been declared as x and y.

    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog( ans1 + input ); //this will combine the two variables and execute the message.

    }
```

Comment: What do you understand from _String [] cannot be converted to String_? What is a `String[]`? What is a `String`? Where are those types involved in the method the error mentions?

Comment: I'm new to java, would be glad if you could explain it to me? :/ @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Just throw the whole `switch` away and use `printmessage(ans1[rand], input);` instead. And maybe read something about [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: My course exercise requires me to use decisions, so I don't want to remove the whole switch away. Is there a way i can make that switch method working? @Tom

Comment: You can call `printmessage(ans1[rand], input);` in every case ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String[] is an array of strings. `printmessage` expects a single String, not an array of them. Give it a string!

aka, pass in the `rand` parameter in your switch statement, which, by the way, is redundant because you're calling the same method.

```
switch (rand) {
    case 0:
    printmessage(ans1[rand], input);
    break;

    case 1:
    printmessage(ans1[rand], input);
    break;

    case 2:
    printmessage(ans1[rand], input);
    break;

    case 3:
    printmessage(ans1[rand], input);
    break;
}
```

Can simply be turned into

```
printmessage(ans1[rand], input);
```